# Pyspark structured streaming - Union data from 2 nested JSON

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have 2 kafka streaming dataframes. The spark schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pmudata1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pmu_id: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- stream_id: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- stat: string (nullable = true)
```

and

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pmudata2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pmu_id: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- stream_id: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- stat: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I union all rows from both streams as they come by specific batch window? Positions of columns in both streams is same.
Each stream have different `pmu_id` value so I can differentiate records per that value.

`UnionByName` or `union` produces stream from single dataframe.

I would need to explode column names I guess, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453083/is-there-any-way-to-flatten-the-nested-json-in-spark-streaming?rq=1) but this is for scala.
Is there a way to automatically explode whole JSON in columns and union them?

Comment: `explode` is for array types. You're looking for `from_json_object`

Comment: The column `pmudata2` is of type struct, simply use `df.selectExpr("key", "pmudata2.*")` to get flattened structure

Comment: @blackbishop I'll try that and let you know results..

Comment: Regarding joins, I assume you've seen this section of the docs? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, I'm aware of that. I'd rather create separate question since I have specific situation.

Comment: @blackbishop that works perfectly. Please put it in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode` function only with array and map types. In your case, the column `pmudata2` has type StructType so simply use star `*` to select all sub-fields like this:

```
df1 = df.selectExpr("key", "pmudata2.*")

#root
#|-- key: string (nullable = true)
#|-- pmu_id: byte (nullable = true)
#|-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
#|-- stream_id: byte (nullable = true)
#|-- stat: string (nullable = true)
```